# Solving a system of linear differential equations with repeated eigen values

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have this problem where to solve the system,
$$x'=4x+y-z$$
$$y'=2x+5y-2z$$
$$z'=x+y+2z$$
using a linear algebraic solution. I have found the eigen values of the 
$$\begin{bmatrix}
        4 & 1 & -1 \\
        2 & 5 & -2 \\
        1 & 1 & 2 \\
        \end{bmatrix}$$
as 3,3 and 5. When evaluating the corresponding eigen vectors for 3, the following occurs.
$$(A-3I)x=0$$
$$\begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 1 & -1 \\
        2 & 2 & -2 \\
        1 & 1 & -1 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} x_1\\ x_2\\ x_3 \end{bmatrix} = 0$$
We can say ok and $x_3=x_1+x_2$ and then a set of eigen vectors which are not multiples of each other are formed. As the next step, I have to find $\rho$ such that $(A-3I)\rho = \eta_{\lambda =3}$. There I'm getting nowhere because of the ambiguity of $\eta_{\lambda=3}$. I am new to this eigen things. Am I doing something terribly wrong or what?

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=eigen+values+of+%5B%5B4,1,-1%5D,%5B2,5,-2%5D,%5B1,1,2%5D%5D ?

Comment: sorry. My differential equation had a typo

Comment: What do you denote $\eta_{\lambda=3}$?

Comment: The eigen vector for the eigen value 3. I made it up by myself :)

Comment: Your $A$ has two linearly independent eigenvectors for $\lambda = 3$.  Why does that cause a problem for you?  The form of the solution is the same as it would be with distinct eigenvalues, using both of those linearly independent eigenvectors.  You would only need to solve $(A-3I) \rho = \eta$ in the case of "missing" eigenvectors.

Comment: let's say $\begin{bmatrix}
        1 \\
        0 \\
        1 \\
        \end{bmatrix}$ and $\begin{bmatrix}0\\ 1\\ 1\\\end{bmatrix}$ to be those independent eigenvectors. Then can we find $\rho$ such that $(A-3I)\rho=\eta$?

Comment: Now I get you @RobertIsrael.Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have correctly calculated your eigenvalues. To avoid ambiguous notation, denote your eigenvalues as follows:

$\lambda_1=5$

$\lambda_2=3$

$\lambda_3=3$.

Using your eigenvalues, use the fact that:
$A\mathbf{x}=\lambda_1 \mathbf{x}$, $A\mathbf{x}=\lambda_2 \mathbf{x}$ and $A\mathbf{x}=\lambda_3 \mathbf{x}$, where $\mathbf{x}=\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\z \end{pmatrix}$ and $A=\begin{pmatrix} 4 & 1 & -1 \\ 2 & 5 & -2 \\ 1 & 1 & 2 \\ \end{pmatrix}$ to evaluate your eigenvectors.

Hence for $\lambda_1$: $\begin{pmatrix} 4 & 1 & -1 \\ 2 & 5 & -2 \\ 1 & 1 & 2 \\ \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x_1\\y_1\\z_1 \end{pmatrix}=5 \begin{pmatrix}x_1\\y_1\\z_1 \end{pmatrix}$.

For $\lambda_2$: $\begin{pmatrix} 4 & 1 & -1 \\ 2 & 5 & -2 \\ 1 & 1 & 2 \\ \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x_2\\y_2\\z_2 \end{pmatrix}=3 \begin{pmatrix}x_2\\y_2\\z_2 \end{pmatrix}$.

For $\lambda_3$: $\begin{pmatrix} 4 & 1 & -1 \\ 2 & 5 & -2 \\ 1 & 1 & 2 \\ \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x_3\\y_3\\z_3 \end{pmatrix}=3 \begin{pmatrix}x_3\\y_3\\z_3 \end{pmatrix}$.

From this, we deduce for $\lambda_1$ the following system:

$4x_1+y_1-z_1=5x_1$

$2x_1+5y_1-2z_1=5y_1$

$x_1+y_1+2z_1=5z_1$

Note that these simultaneous equations are redundant – they are all essentially the same. Hence, we deduce from one of these equations that $y_1=x_1+z_1$.

We repeat the same process for $\lambda_2$ (no need for $\lambda_3$ since both have same eigenvalues) and obtain $z_2=x_2+y_2$, as you mentioned earlier. The next step to find the eigenvectors is to find the smallest possible nonzero integer values for $x_n, y_n, z_n$ for each of your corresponding eigenvalues such that it satisfies your equation. These are your eigenvectors.

For $\lambda_1$, we obtain $v_1=\begin{pmatrix}1\\2\\1 \end{pmatrix}$. For $\lambda_2$ we obtain two possible solutions $v_2=\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\1 \end{pmatrix}$ and $v_3=\begin{pmatrix}-1\\1\\0 \end{pmatrix}$. The eigenvectors will be the same for $\lambda_3$.

Therefore, from the eigenvalues and eigenvectors, we may substitute and obtain the general solutions:

$\begin{pmatrix}x(t)\\y(t)\\z(t) \end{pmatrix}=c_1\begin{pmatrix}1\\2\\1 \end{pmatrix}e^{5t}+c_2\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\1 \end{pmatrix}e^{3t}+c_3\begin{pmatrix}-1\\1\\0 \end{pmatrix}e^{3t}$.

Please do not hesitate to ask if you have any doubts or questions.

Comment: Thank you very much! So there is no need to find $\rho$ as in http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/RepeatedEigenvalues.aspx because there are no any repeated eigenvectors but only repeated eigenvalues.

Comment: We already did find $\vec{\eta}$ and $\vec{\rho}$ on $\vec{v_1}$, $\vec{v_2}$ and $\vec{v_3}$, since they are your eigenvectors. Just that in this case, we have 3 eigenvalues and 3 eigenvectors, so we have to extend our solution to $Y=c_1 \vec{v_1} e^{\lambda_1⋅t}+c_2 \vec{v_2} e^{\lambda_2 t}+c_3 \vec{v_3} e^{\lambda_3 t}$

Comment: Thank you so much.. I appreciate your help